# Difficulty solving "sh: <npm package name> command not found" with npm run <npm package name>

Tags: npm

I've been adding npm modules to my project for the first time (jshint, optimg, jpgo). I notice that some projects, when I do **npm run [name]**, give a result of "sh: [name]: command not found."

I can't figure out why those don't work, but the other npm installs do. All these are installed locally; I can see the install by looking in the /node_modules folder in my project root and verify them with **npm ls.**

The latest package that gets this error is html-minify. My package.json looks like this (and validates at http://jsonlint.com/):

```
{
    "name": "npmTest",
    "devDependencies": {
        "jshint": "latest",
        "optimg": "latest",
        "jpgo": "latest",
        "ycssmin": "latest",
        "html-minify": "latest"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "jshint **.js",
        "png": "optimg",
        "jpg": "jpgo",
        "css": "ycssmin **.css",
        "html": "html-minify"

    }
}
```

I tried "html-minify **.html" with the same resulting "not found" error.

*Why would I get "sh: [npm package name]: command not found"?* I've read the other threads, and because the other modules work, I doubt that I need to add anything to my PATH, or start a server, or install globally.

Fuller error message (for html5-lint):

```
$ npm run html

> npmTest@ html /Users/Steve/Documents/APPS/Test_Apps/npmTest
> html5-lint

sh: html5-lint: command not found

npm ERR! npmTest@ html: `html5-lint`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the npmTest@ html script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the npmTest package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     html5-lint
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls npmTest
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "html"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Steve/Documents/APPS/Test_Apps/npmTest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Steve/Documents/APPS/Test_Apps/npmTest/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-110-generic x86_64),
node 6.10.0,
npm 3.10.10. 
The same issue.

Answer (score 2):

so short answer to run npm package commands locally

```
npm i install cowsay -d
```

then use

```
npx cowsay I am working locally
```

output should be

```
______
< I am working locally  >
 ------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

on the other hand installing npm packages globaly on linux has problems with addministrator and node-module location

so best practice to get global packges to work normally is to install NVM first

```
sudo apt install curl
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
source ~/.profile
```

then once nvm is installed install from nvm node

```
nvm install node
```

or a specific version

```
nvm install 12.18.3
```

now installing global packages and running them is simple

```
npm install -g cowsay

cowsay I am working globaly
```

will output

```
______
< I am working  >
 ------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

now global packages are working fine and local packages can be run from the directory of the project using npx.

Answer (score -1):

For the command not found issue you're seeing with html-minifier it could have to do with not globally installing the npm package (with a -g) or calling the command by the wrong name (I believe you're calling the package name html-minify when the package is defined as html-minifier)

Would suggest installing the command with a -g:

```
npm install html-minifier -g
```

and then running the html-minifier command:

```
html-minifier --help (to test installation)
html-minifier --collapse-whitespace --remove-comments --remove-optional-tags --remove-redundant-attributes --remove-script-type-attributes --remove-tag-whitespace --use-short-doctype --minify-css true --minify-js true
```

Also for the scripts issue you're observing (where running npm run html is returning command not found)- here is a sample package.json. I ran npm run html (after globally installing html-minifier using the step above) and that runs html-minifier --help:

```
 {
   "name": "stackoverflow",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "html": "html-minifier --help"
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies": {
     "html-minifier": "^4.0.0"
   }
```

}

Github link: https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier

Npm link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier

Installation and usage steps provided in the README:

### Installation Instructions

From NPM for use as a command line app:

```sh
npm install html-minifier -g
```

From NPM for programmatic use:

```sh
npm install html-minifier
```

From Git:

```sh
git clone git://github.com/kangax/html-minifier.git
cd html-minifier
npm link .
```

### Usage

Note that almost all options are disabled by default. For command line usage please see `html-minifier --help` for a list of available options. Experiment and find what works best for you and your project.

- **Sample command line:** `html-minifier --collapse-whitespace --remove-comments --remove-optional-tags --remove-redundant-attributes --remove-script-type-attributes --remove-tag-whitespace --use-short-doctype --minify-css true --minify-js true`

#### Node.js

```js
var minify = require('html-minifier').minify;
var result = minify('<p title="blah" id="moo">foo</p>', {
  removeAttributeQuotes: true
});
result; // '<p title=blah id=moo>foo</p>'
```